# How to aggregate or join two JSON datasets in Splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I try to build up an overview some process steps of my application.
I generate two JSON documents

```
{ 
  "requestID": "abc-123",
  "username": "ringo",
}
```

and

```
{  
  "requestID": "abc-123",
  "favoriteCar": "Lada"
}
```

ok, now I have also other entries like these:

- abc-456 / paul / Fiat
- bcd-987 / george / Talbot

and so on ... linked by the requestID

Now I want to do a table that shows me:

```
ID       |  Username    |     Car
---------|--------------|---------------
abc-123  | ringo        | Lada
abc-456  | paul         | Fiat
bcd-987  | george       | Talbot
```

So my question is: How can I do these aggregation?

Kind regards

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregations are done with the [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) command.  Once you have the fields extracted, they can be grouped using `stats values(*) as * by requestID`.